# Runtime Change UIbutton position after changing its font name

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

when I am changing `UIButton` font name. then it will also change its x position . I am using custom font

I have attached `image` . In this `image` you will get idea. How can I solve this problem?

Thanking you.

Comment: post your code that changes the font

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the contentHorizontalAlignment:

```
btn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
```

You might also want to adjust the content left inset otherwise the text will touch the left border:

```
btn.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be because you are using autoRelease method

```
[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Try to use `initWithFrame:`.

May be this will help. I havn't tried it.
Try it.
OR

May be need to set

```
btn_Trade = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
```

Same for all buttons.

Regards,
Neelam Verma

Answer (score 1):

You have given alignmnet to only this button

```
[btn_Trade setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter];
```

Try giving alignment to rest of the buttons also according to your needs but make sure all the buttons have same allignment.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of the spacings which are left by default by a font. Means the positioning of characters in a font differs. Immediate solution is set the position of the button after you are done with setting the font.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have also try this , set the postion of the uibutton after setting the font . But same thing happen...